# WinRAR storing file paths

Tags: winrar

There is an option whether to store full paths or relative paths while compressing files using *WinRAR*.

What is meant by this? What exactly do the various options on creating a RAR file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this question is off-topic here on Stack Overflow as it is not a question related to programming.

And by pressing key **F1** or clicking on button **Help** the appropriate help page for the active dialog opens where the *File paths* option is explained briefly, too. However, I answer the question nevertheless.

Let's say you have a file and directory structure as this in root of drive **C**:

- **Temp**

  - **FolderToArchive**

    - **Folder A**

      - File X
      - File Y
      - File Z
    - **Folder B**

      - File A
      - File B
      - File C
    - File 1
    - File 2
    - File X

You select the folder with name **FolderToArchive** and click on button **Add** in the toolbar.

---

*Store relative paths* creates an archive containing:

```
FolderToArchive\Folder A\File X
FolderToArchive\Folder A\File Y
FolderToArchive\Folder A\File Z
FolderToArchive\Folder B\File A
FolderToArchive\Folder B\File B
FolderToArchive\Folder B\File C
FolderToArchive\File 1
FolderToArchive\File 2
FolderToArchive\File X
```

This is like using command line option `-ep1` on running *RAR* or *WinRAR* from command line.

---

*Store full paths* creates an archive containing:

```
Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder A\File X
Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder A\File Y
Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder A\File Z
Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder B\File A
Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder B\File B
Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder B\File C
Temp\FolderToArchive\File 1
Temp\FolderToArchive\File 2
Temp\FolderToArchive\File X
```

This is like using command line option `-ep2` on command line.

---

*Do not store paths* creates an archive containing:

```
File X
File Y
File Z
File A
File B
File C
File 1
File 2
File X
```

There are two `File X` in archive without path. This is of course problematic on extraction.

The equivalent command line option is `-ep`.

---

*Store full paths including the drive letter* creates an archive containing:

```
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder A\File X
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder A\File Y
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder A\File Z
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder B\File A
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder B\File B
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\Folder B\File C
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\File 1
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\File 2
C_\Temp\FolderToArchive\File X
```

The appropriate command line option is `-ep3`.

---

See text file **Rar.txt** in program files folder of *WinRAR* where an explanation of all the command line options for console version *RAR* can be found. Help of *WinRAR* contains also a description of all commands and options specific for GUI version *WinRAR*.